# Why mininet default controller always work in loop back interface 127.0.0.1

Tags: mininet

Why mininet default controller always work in loop back interface 127.0.0.1 and why ip cannot change in default controller ? If any one can help me please thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to expand out your question a bit more. It doesn't look like you put much work into it. If you aren't willing to put work into explaining and clarifying your question, how can you expect others to put work into answer your question?

Comment: Hi Alex in Mininet I try to create open flow network 2 controllers 2 switches and 4 hosts I used the the controllers3.py Python script to make this network now I want to change the ip in the controller when I change the ip it won't work (I mean ping ) controller default ip always stays as 127.0.0.1

Comment: Well, does the controller have an actual IP address, is it remote or local? If you start a controller on your local machine the IP address will be 127.0.0.1. If you want the controller to have another IP address you have to create it on a machine with its own IP address, and thereby be a "remote controller". You cant just say that the local controller should have a remote address, it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways using command line:

```
--controller remote,ip=value
--controller=remote --ip=value --port=value
```

In custom script:

```
from mininet.node import RemoteController
net = Mininet(topo, switch=switch, controller=RemoteController)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general form:

```
$ sudo mn --topo single,3 --mac --switch ovsk --controller remote,ip=<controller_ip>
```

Here is an example:

```
$ sudo mn --topo single,3 --mac --switch ovsk --controller remote,ip=192.168.206.2
```

Here is an example of another form:

```
sudo mn --controller=remote --ip=127.0.0.1 --port=6633 --mac --topo=linear
```

Source: https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Create-a-Learning-Switch